# when I deallocate an array of strings my program crashes

Tags: c

i need to allocate an array of strings. 100 in length, and each cell can contain a string size of 100 characters.

```
typedef char* (*Encryptor3)(char*, char);
char** encryptToString(char** input,int length,int first,Encryptor3 encryptor)
{
int i=0;
char** output=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*length);
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    output[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(100+1));
}
output[0]=encryptor(first,input[0]);
output[1]=encryptor(first,input[1]);

for(i=2; i<length ; i++)
{
    output[i]=encryptor(output[i-2],input[i]);
}
return output;
}

int main()
{
    char plain[] = {'p','l','a','i','n','t','e','x','t'};
    char** outputS = encryptToString(plain, 9, "test", idenString);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        printf("%s\n", outputS[i]);
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) //deallocating my array of strings
        free(outputS[i]);
    free(outputS);
    return 0;
}
```

the line "free(outputS[i]);" will crash the program and i'll get an ordinary error saying "myp.exe has stopped working".

Comment: Why are you passing `"test"` as an `int` parameter?

Comment: `output[i]=encryptor(output[i-2],input[i]);` memory leak.  Aside form that, how is the return value of `encryptor` allocated?

Comment: These lines `output[0]=encryptor(first,input[0]);` (etc) are *replacing* your variable, so it isn't using the `malloc`ed space

Comment: It would be helpful to have complete code. `idenString` is missing. It would be helpful to have complete code. `idenString` is missing. I assume this is homework from the PL course at the Technion, so `idenString` just return it's first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
output[...]=encryptor(...);
```

do:

```
strcpy(output[...], encryptor(...));
```

This assumes the buffer used by `encryptor()` is static.

Also make sure the string returned by `encryptor()` isn't larger then what you allocated to the pointers referenced by `output`, that is 100 characters, excluding the trailing zero-termination.

Comment: I didn't except an answer this good! it works like a charm now
you even noticed other things i did wrong.
thank you!
(changed first variable from int to char* and from output[...]=encryptor(...); to strcpy(output[...], encryptor(...));)

Comment: @A'merMograbi: As you seemed to feel the answer is useful you are free to accept it (by clicking it's exclamation mark) and if you liked it you might also upvote it ... ;-)